# InDesign Script not working when dialog window is added

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript, adobe-scriptui, grep-indesign

I am trying to create a script based on GREPs that replaces fonts in non-latin characters with a compatible font, but when I add it to a dialog window it does not work anymore (it works by itself).
I have identified the point where it stops running and it's between these two lines:

```
var options = app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties;

app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
```

When I debug the script, I get the following error: Runtime Error: Error Code# 30486: Cannot handle the request because a modal dialog or alert is active.

There should be no dialog or alert at that point, and this doesn't happen when I run the script on its own. Can someone give me a hand here? I don't really understand why this is happening.
The complete script is this one:

```
var dialog = new Window("dialog"); 
    dialog.text = "Asian font replacement"; 
    dialog.orientation = "column"; 
    dialog.alignChildren = ["center","top"]; 
    dialog.spacing = 10; 
    dialog.margins = 16; 

// GROUP1
// ======
var group1 = dialog.add("group", undefined, {name: "group1"}); 
    group1.orientation = "row"; 
    group1.alignChildren = ["left","center"]; 
    group1.spacing = 10; 
    group1.margins = 0; 

var statictext1 = group1.add("statictext", undefined, undefined, {name: "statictext1"}); 
    statictext1.text = "Select the language"; 

var languages_array = ["-","Japanese","Simplified Chinese","Traditional Chinese","Korean","Thai"]; 
var languages = group1.add("dropdownlist", undefined, undefined, {name: "languages", items: languages_array}); 
    languages.selection = 0; 
    languages.preferredSize.width = 88; 

// GROUP2
// ======
var group2 = dialog.add("group", undefined, {name: "group2"}); 
    group2.orientation = "row"; 
    group2.alignChildren = ["left","center"]; 
    group2.spacing = 10; 
    group2.margins = 0; 

var Closebutton = group2.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "Closebutton"}); 
    Closebutton.text = "Cancel"; 
    Closebutton.justify = "left"; 
    Closebutton.alignment = ["left","top"]; 

var Runbutton = group2.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "Runbutton"}); 
    Runbutton.text = "Run"; 
    Runbutton.alignment = ["left","bottom"]; 


Runbutton.onClick = function(){
    if (languages.selection == "1")
{
    dialog.close();
    JP();
    alert("Font has been applied")  
}
    if (languages.selection == "4")
{
    dialog.close();
    KO();  
    alert("Font has been applied")
}
};

//Japanese GREP

function  JP() {
    if (app.layoutWindows.length == 0) return;
    var changeObject = app.documents[0];
    if (changeObject.hasOwnProperty('characters') && changeObject.characters.length == 0) return;
    var doc = app.documents[0];
    var style;
    var scriptVersion = app.scriptPreferences.version;
    app.scriptPreferences.version.constructor.name // Result:String
    var options = app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties;
    //it stops here
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    
// Query [[JP_black]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Black"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_bold]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_bolditalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Bold", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_heavy]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_italic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Regular ", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_light]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Light"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_lightitalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Light", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_reg]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Regular"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Regular "});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_semib1]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semi Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_semib2]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semibold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = options;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.scriptPreferences.version = scriptVersion;
};

function getStyleByString(docOrGroup, string, property) {
    if (string == '[No character style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == '[No paragraph style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == 'NormalParagraphStyle') return docOrGroup[property][1];
    stringResult = string.match (/^(.*?[^\\]):(.*)$/);
    var styleName = (stringResult) ? stringResult[1] : string;
    styleName = styleName.replace (/\\:/g, ':');
    remainingString = (stringResult) ? stringResult[2] : '';
    var newProperty = (stringResult) ? property.replace(/s$/, '') + 'Groups' : property;
    var styleOrGroup = docOrGroup[newProperty].itemByName(styleName);
    if (remainingString.length > 0 && styleOrGroup.isValid) styleOrGroup = getStyleByString (styleOrGroup, remainingString, property);
    return styleOrGroup;
};

// KO GREP
function KO() {
    if (app.layoutWindows.length == 0) return;
    var changeObject = app.documents[0];
    if (changeObject.hasOwnProperty('characters') && changeObject.characters.length == 0) return;
    var doc = app.documents[0];
    var style;
    var scriptVersion = app.scriptPreferences.version;
    app.scriptPreferences.version = 15.1;
    var options = app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_black]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Black"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_bold]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_bolditalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Bold", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_heavy]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_italic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Regular ", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_light]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Light"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_lightitalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Light", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_reg]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Regular"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Regular "});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_semib1]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semi Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_semib2]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semibold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = options;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.scriptPreferences.version = scriptVersion;
};

function getStyleByString(docOrGroup, string, property) {
    if (string == '[No character style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == '[No paragraph style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == 'NormalParagraphStyle') return docOrGroup[property][1];
    stringResult = string.match (/^(.*?[^\\]):(.*)$/);
    var styleName = (stringResult) ? stringResult[1] : string;
    styleName = styleName.replace (/\\:/g, ':');
    remainingString = (stringResult) ? stringResult[2] : '';
    var newProperty = (stringResult) ? property.replace(/s$/, '') + 'Groups' : property;
    var styleOrGroup = docOrGroup[newProperty].itemByName(styleName);
    if (remainingString.length > 0 && styleOrGroup.isValid) styleOrGroup = getStyleByString (styleOrGroup, remainingString, property);
    return styleOrGroup;
};



dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactored script (below) includes the following changes:

1. All your logic for the ScriptUI dialog is now inside a `createConfigDialog` function.

   - In the body of the `createConfigDialog` function we also define a `hasChosen` variable, i.e.

     ```js
     var hasChosen = undefined;
     ```
   - In the `onClick` event handler we assign the result of whatever the user selected to the `hasChosen` variable. For instance:

     ```js
     Runbutton.onClick = function() {
         if (languages.selection.text === "Japanese") {
             hasChosen = "Japanese";
         }
         if (languages.selection.text === "Korean") {
             hasChosen = "Korean";
         }
         dialog.close();
     };
     ```
   - The `createConfigDialog` finally then returns an object with a `hasChosen` property. It's value is either `Japanese` or `Korean`.  For instance:

     ```js
     return {
         hasChosen: hasChosen
     }
     ```
2. In the `main` function ([IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)) we invoke the `createConfigDialog` function.

   - Then conditionally invoke either the `JP()`, or `KO()` function according to the value of the `hasChosen` property that was returned. For instance:

     ```js
     (function main() {

         var dialog = createConfigDialog();

         if (dialog.hasChosen === "Japanese") {
             JP();
             alert("Font has been applied")
         } else if (dialog.hasChosen === "Korean") {
             KO();
             alert("Font has been applied")
         }

     }());
     ```

---

#### Complete refactored script:

```js
function createConfigDialog() {

    var dialog = new Window("dialog");
        dialog.text = "Asian font replacement";
        dialog.orientation = "column";
        dialog.alignChildren = ["center","top"];
        dialog.spacing = 10;
        dialog.margins = 16;

    // GROUP1
    // ======
    var group1 = dialog.add("group", undefined, {name: "group1"});
        group1.orientation = "row";
        group1.alignChildren = ["left","center"];
        group1.spacing = 10;
        group1.margins = 0;

    var statictext1 = group1.add("statictext", undefined, undefined, {name: "statictext1"});
        statictext1.text = "Select the language";

    var languages_array = ["-","Japanese","Simplified Chinese","Traditional Chinese","Korean","Thai"];
    var languages = group1.add("dropdownlist", undefined, undefined, {name: "languages", items: languages_array});
        languages.selection = 0;
        languages.preferredSize.width = 88;

    // GROUP2
    // ======
    var group2 = dialog.add("group", undefined, {name: "group2"});
        group2.orientation = "row";
        group2.alignChildren = ["left","center"];
        group2.spacing = 10;
        group2.margins = 0;

    var Closebutton = group2.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "Closebutton"});
        Closebutton.text = "Cancel";
        Closebutton.justify = "left";
        Closebutton.alignment = ["left","top"];

    var Runbutton = group2.add("button", undefined, undefined, {name: "Runbutton"});
        Runbutton.text = "Run";
        Runbutton.alignment = ["left","bottom"];


    var hasChosen = undefined;

    Runbutton.onClick = function() {
        if (languages.selection.text === "Japanese") {
            hasChosen = "Japanese";
        }
        if (languages.selection.text === "Korean") {
            hasChosen = "Korean";
        }
        dialog.close();
    };

    var showDialog = dialog.show();

    if (showDialog === 2) { // User clicked `Cancel` button.
      exit();
    }

    return {
        hasChosen: hasChosen
    }
};

//Japanese GREP

function JP() {
    if (app.layoutWindows.length == 0) return;
    var changeObject = app.documents[0];
    if (changeObject.hasOwnProperty('characters') && changeObject.characters.length == 0) return;
    var doc = app.documents[0];
    var style;
    var scriptVersion = app.scriptPreferences.version;
    app.scriptPreferences.version.constructor.name // Result:String
    var options = app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties;
    //it stops here
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;

    // Query [[JP_black]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Black"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_bold]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_bolditalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Bold", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_heavy]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_italic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Regular ", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_light]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Light"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_lightitalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Light", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_reg]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Regular"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Regular "});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_semib1]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semi Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[JP_semib2]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semibold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1248357235, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans JP", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = options;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.scriptPreferences.version = scriptVersion;
};

function getStyleByString(docOrGroup, string, property) {
    if (string == '[No character style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == '[No paragraph style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == 'NormalParagraphStyle') return docOrGroup[property][1];
    stringResult = string.match (/^(.*?[^\\]):(.*)$/);
    var styleName = (stringResult) ? stringResult[1] : string;
    styleName = styleName.replace (/\\:/g, ':');
    remainingString = (stringResult) ? stringResult[2] : '';
    var newProperty = (stringResult) ? property.replace(/s$/, '') + 'Groups' : property;
    var styleOrGroup = docOrGroup[newProperty].itemByName(styleName);
    if (remainingString.length > 0 && styleOrGroup.isValid) styleOrGroup = getStyleByString (styleOrGroup, remainingString, property);
    return styleOrGroup;
};

// KO GREP
function KO() {
    if (app.layoutWindows.length == 0) return;
    var changeObject = app.documents[0];
    if (changeObject.hasOwnProperty('characters') && changeObject.characters.length == 0) return;
    var doc = app.documents[0];
    var style;
    var scriptVersion = app.scriptPreferences.version;
    app.scriptPreferences.version = 15.1;
    var options = app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_black]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Black"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_bold]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Bold"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_bolditalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Bold Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Bold", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_heavy]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Heavy"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_italic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Regular ", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_light]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Light"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_lightitalic]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Light Italic"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Light", skew:11});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_reg]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Regular"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Regular "});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_semib1]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semi Bold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    // Query [[KO_semib2]] -- If you delete this comment you break the update function
    try {
        app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = ({includeFootnotes:true, kanaSensitive:true, widthSensitive:true});
        app.findGrepPreferences.properties = ({findWhat:"[^.,;:?!-()%&\\[\\]\\d a-z|A-Z]+", fontStyle:"Semibold"});
        app.changeGrepPreferences.properties = ({kinsokuSet:1263692659, composer:"Adobe Japanese Paragraph Composer", appliedFont:"Source Han Sans KR", fontStyle:"Medium"});
        changeObject.changeGrep();
    } catch (e) {alert(e + ' at line ' + e.line)}
    app.findChangeGrepOptions.properties = options;
    app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.changeGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.NOTHING;
    app.scriptPreferences.version = scriptVersion;
};

function getStyleByString(docOrGroup, string, property) {
    if (string == '[No character style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == '[No paragraph style]') return docOrGroup[property][0];
    if (string == 'NormalParagraphStyle') return docOrGroup[property][1];
    stringResult = string.match (/^(.*?[^\\]):(.*)$/);
    var styleName = (stringResult) ? stringResult[1] : string;
    styleName = styleName.replace (/\\:/g, ':');
    remainingString = (stringResult) ? stringResult[2] : '';
    var newProperty = (stringResult) ? property.replace(/s$/, '') + 'Groups' : property;
    var styleOrGroup = docOrGroup[newProperty].itemByName(styleName);
    if (remainingString.length > 0 && styleOrGroup.isValid) styleOrGroup = getStyleByString (styleOrGroup, remainingString, property);
    return styleOrGroup;
};


(function main() {

    var dialog = createConfigDialog();

    if (dialog.hasChosen === "Japanese") {
        JP();
        alert("Font has been applied")
    } else if (dialog.hasChosen === "Korean") {
        KO();
        alert("Font has been applied")
    }

}());
```

---

<sub>**Additional notes regarding code style:**</sub>

<sub>By convention a variable name that begin with a capitalized name, such as `KO` and `JP` indicates that it is a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) function, and should therefore be called with the [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) operator. As both `JP` and `KO` functions are not constructors in your code, I suggest you consider making them lowercase, e.g. `jp` and `ko` respectively (or e.g. `japan` and `korean`).</sub>

<sub>Similarly with `Runbutton` and `Closebutton` - change instances of them to e.g. `runButton` and `closeButton` respectively, to omit the capitalized first letter.</sub>